# Regex to allow only letters and numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string, alphanumeric

Hello currently I'm using this regex:

```
alphaNumeric = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

for my custom TextBox. So when I press a key it only adds to the TextBox's `string` if it is:

- an English letter
- a number
- not a space
- <s>not a punctuation symbol</s>

The above 3 work except for the 4th condition. Could you provide me with a regex that filters the string so that it only contains English letters or numbers AND **NOT** spaces and punctuation marks like these:

```
,./;'\[]
<>?:"|{}
!@#$%^&*()-=_+
```

Comment: The `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` regex does not allow typing the punctuation and spaces. The problem is with your code.

Comment: Then I'll have to check where the problem is in my current code.

Comment: Or post the code here for SO users to help you further.

Comment: Or, post a limited subset of the problem code that can duplicate the issue. Don't post names/phone numbers/credit card numbers, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the issue, I was validating the string during the `TextBox` object's creation, instead of when it updates so there was no way for that code to be executed when it was needed. My bad.